# Why do I get a new line asking me to introduce a number when I ask the second number of a matrix in C?

Tags: c, scanf

I have this simple code to read a matrix from the keyboard.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"functii.h"

int main()
{
    float a[50][50];
    float t[50][50];
    int n; //linii si coloanele

    printf("\n Enter the rows and col of the matrix=");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    citireMatrice(a,n); //read the matrix
    //afisareMatrice(a,n); //show the matrix

    return 0;
}
```

with functii.c

```
void citireMatrice(float x[50][50],int n)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;++j)
        {
        printf("a[%d][%d]=",i,j);
        scanf("%f ",&x[i][j]);
        }
    }

}
```

The header has the prototype.
The problem is that when I run the program, after I enter the first number, I get a blank line without text, allowing me to enter the second number and the the algorithm continues, not storing the last number entered.
It is something like this:

```
a[0][0]=1
2 //entered by me
a[0][1]=3
a[0][2]=1
a[1][0]=2
a[1][1]=3
a[1][2]=1
a[2][0]=2
a[2][1]=3
a[2][2]=4
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000
```

Comment: That doesn't look right, it should at least prompt you to enter `n`. Can you post the exact thing that gets displayed please? Are you running the program using Eclipse's console or something like that?

Comment: `"%f "` --> `"%f"` : remove space after `f`.

Answer (score 0):

[@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) [has already explained how to solve the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974839/why-do-i-get-a-new-line-asking-me-to-introduce-a-number-when-i-ask-the-second-nu#comment46201262_28974839).

The reason is because of the space after `%f` here:

```
scanf("%f ",&x[i][j]);
       //^ This space is the trouble-maker
```

A space is a whitespace character. Lets see what the C11 standard has to say about that:

> **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 5. A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails.

So, the space character consumes all whitespace characters(if any) **until the first non-whitespace character**.

When you enter a number to be scanned and press enter, the number is consumed by the `%f` in the `scanf` while the space discards the newline character and then waits.... waits until it encounters a non-whitespace character. This is why you have to enter an extra number for the space in the `scanf` to stop discarding whitespace characters.